# How to regain acccess in read/write to download directory in Android Typescript Nativescript 8.5.3 and compileSdkVersion 33?

Tags: android, typescript, nativescript, android-permissions

Since upgrading my Nativescript installation, the permissions don't work anymore on the storage.

Previously, i use the old android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, with gradle settings as :
compileSdkVersion 33
minSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 29

The android where the app is deployed are only android 10, the dependancies of Nativescript force to compileSdkVersion 33.

But just making a ns update and migrating to a newer version of @nativescript/core (from 8.5.1 to 8.5.9), the requesting permissions doesnt work anymore (access denied on Download directory with File.readTextSync() and moreover the Settings page of the application in android menu has changed and no more Storage permissions setting ...

I've struggle hours to find an alternative but didn't find any recent working sample/help for Nativescript (typescript) just to read/write files on Download directory of the phone.

Previously i used ;
const permissions = require('nativescript-permissions'); ->crash on requesting permissions for storage (promise retunr exception with exception message undefined)
And make test with ;
const permissions = require('@nativescript-community/perms'); -> no error in requesting permissions but access denied error on readTextSync().

I checked if android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is available but it's not granted.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really simple and need you adjust the android manifest file like below. Using this method you don't have to modify your code :

Add the xmlns of tools if not done :

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Modify the permissions to limit the sdk used :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:replace="android:maxSdkVersion" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" /
```